# Assistance with C Program: Solving for Delta

Tags: c, output

I need to make a program in C that takes 3 coefficients, a, b, c, then solves for Delta. It then takes Delta and decides what Function to send it to determine it's output.

```
  /* 
  *Program Name: COP 2220-10018 Project 4
  *
  * Author: Nathan Gamble
  * 
  * Description: Find Delta, solve for roots.
  *
  * Input: Coefficients a, b, c.
  *
  * Output: Roots
  */
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 int main (void)                        


    {
//Local Declarations
float a;
float b;
float c;
float delta;


//Statements
printf("Input coefficient a.\n");
scanf("%.2f", &a);
printf("Input coefficient b.\n");
scanf("%.2f", &b);
printf("Input coefficient c.\n");
scanf("%.2f", &c);
printf("%fx^2 + %fx + %f\n", &a, &b, &c);

//Process
delta = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);

if (delta > 0) twoRoots(a, b, c, delta);
else if (delta = 0) oneRoot(a, b, c, delta);
else if (delta < 0) noRoots();

return;
} // End main


/* 
 *Program Name: COP 2220-10018 Project 4
 *
 * Author: Nathan Gamble
 * 
 * Description: To solve for the two roots.
 *
 * Input: None
 *
 * Output: Root one, Root two.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int twoRoots ()
{
//Local Declarations
float xOne;
float xTwo;
float delta;
float deltaRoot;
float a;
float b;

printf("There are two distinct roots.\n");
deltaRoot = sqrt(delta);
xOne = (-b + deltaRoot) / (2*a);
xTwo = (-b - deltaRoot) / (2*a);
printf("%.2f", &xOne);
printf("%.2f", &xTwo);

return;
} // End twoRoots


/* 
 *Program Name: COP 2220-10018 Project 4
 *
 * Author: Nathan Gamble
 * 
 * Description: To solve for the one root.
 *
 * Input: None
 *
 * Output: Root one.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int oneRoot ()
{
//Local Declarations
float xOne;
float xTwo;
float deltaRoot;
float a;
float b;

printf("There is exactly one distinct root./n");
xOne = -b / (2*a);
printf("%.2f", &xOne);


return;
} // End oneRoot


/* 
 *Program Name: COP 2220-10018 Project 4
 *
 * Author: Nathan Gamble
 * 
 * Description: To inform the roots are complex.
 *
 * Input: None
 *
 * Output: Statement.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int noRoots ()
{
//Local Declarations

printf("There are two distinct complex roots./n");

return;
} // End noRoots
```

When I run it, I get the following Output:

```
Input coefficient a.
1
Input coefficient b.
Input coefficient c.
0.000000x^2 + 882156984598706310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000x + 0.000000

Process returned 16384 (0x4000)   execution time : 10.641 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I only input 1, for a, and then it spits outt he remainder of the main method.

Comment: Now what is the question?

Comment: How do I get it to work?
Suggestions to fix the code so I can correctly input for a, b, and c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things that jump out first:

```
printf("Input coefficient a.\n");
scanf("%f", &a);     // you were scanning for 0.2f .. any reason why?
printf("Input coefficient b.\n");
scanf("%f", &b);
printf("Input coefficient c.\n");
scanf("%f", &c);
```

your `printf` is also wrong .. change it to this:

```
printf("%0.2fx^2 + %0.2fx + %0.2f\n", a, b, c); // you were printing the addresses of a,b,c .. printf just needs the name of variables not their addresses
```

---

**Output after doing above changes:**

```
$ ./test
Input coefficient a.
1.5
Input coefficient b.
2.5
Input coefficient c.
3.5
1.50x^2 + 2.50x + 3.50
```

---

**Fixed code:** ( ask me if you have questions about any part )

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

// function declarations

void twoRoots (float a,float b,float delta);
void oneRoot (float a,float b,float delta);

 int main (void)                        
    {
    //Local Declarations
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float delta;

    float solution;

    printf("Input coefficient a.\n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Input coefficient b.\n");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("Input coefficient c.\n");
    scanf("%f", &c);
    printf("%0.2fx^2 + %0.2fx + %0.2f\n", a, b, c);

    delta = (float)(b*b) - (float)(4.0 * a * c);

    printf("delta = %0.2f\n",delta);

    if (delta > 0){
         twoRoots(a,b,delta);
    }else if (delta == 0) {
         oneRoot(a,b,delta);
    }else if (delta < 0.0){
         printf("There are no real roots\n");
    }

    return 0;
} 

void twoRoots (float a,float b,float delta)
{

    float xOne;
    float xTwo;

    float deltaRoot;

    printf("There are two distinct roots.\n");
    deltaRoot = sqrt(delta);
    xOne = (-b + deltaRoot) / (2*a);
    xTwo = (-b - deltaRoot) / (2*a);
    printf("%.2f", xOne);
    printf("%.2f", xTwo);
} 



void oneRoot(float a,float b,float delta)
{

    float xOne;
    float xTwo;
    float deltaRoot;

    printf("There is exactly one distinct root\n");
    xOne = -b / (2*a);
    printf("%.2f", xOne);

}
```

**Output1:**

```
$ ./test
Input coefficient a.
1.1
Input coefficient b.
5.5
Input coefficient c.
2.2
1.10x^2 + 5.50x + 2.20
delta = 20.57
There are two distinct roots.
-0.44-4.56
```

**Output2:**

```
$ ./test
Input coefficient a.
1
Input coefficient b.
4
Input coefficient c.
4
1.00x^2 + 4.00x + 4.00
delta = 0.00
There is exactly one distinct root
-2.00
```

**Output3:**

```
$ ./test
Input coefficient a.
1
Input coefficient b.
3
Input coefficient c.
9
1.00x^2 + 3.00x + 9.00
delta = -27.00
There are no real roots
```

---

**I optimised the code and made it a whole lot more efficient here :**

http://pastebin.com/GS65PvH6

Comment: One of the specifications for my Project (Which is for class) is that I read and print all values with precision 2 decimal places.

Comment: @LinkNoneya see the latest edit and tell me if that is what you want?

Comment: That worked, thank you.
If I could ask another question, the program stops after it outputs ax^2 +bx + c.
How do I get the program to solve for Delta and apss Delta along to the rest of the Methods?

Comment: @LinkNoneya there are so many problems with your code .. give me 10 min to solve them .. i will post the fixed code soon

Comment: I've removed duplicate variable declarations from the other Functions.

I would still declare new ones, like xOne, xTwo, and deltaRoot, right?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I'm new to coding. I learn by example, but unfortunately my teacher has a more "do it yourself" style approach.

Comment: @LinkNoneya .. i just changed the code a little .. please look at the latest edit

Comment: @LinkNoneya if you find this answer please accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem lies here:

```
scanf ("%.2f", &a);
```

You *can* put a length limiter on the value to be scanned but you probably shouldn't be trying to limit what's input anyway.

In any case, the `.2` option you're using is not valid for `scanf`, it's a `printf` thing controlling the precision of the output.

The ISO standard states that `scanf` needs "an optional decimal integer *greater than zero* that specifies the maximum field width (in characters)". So there's no way using *just* `scanf` to limit how many digits are allowed after the decimal point.

Use this instead:

```
scanf ("%f", &a);
```

including for the other `scanf` calls.

---

As to further problems,  there are a few, some of which are below. I haven't provided an exhaustive list as the problem specific to your question is the `scanf` format string.

First, you want to print the *values* of those variables rather than their addresses:

```
printf ("%fx^2 + %fx + %f\n", a, b, c);
```

Second, you pass the variables `a/b/c/delta` to your functions but you do not receive them. You need to declare them something like:

```
int twoRoots (float a, float b, float c, float delta)
```

and ensure you remove any local variable declarations for those names so that they don't hide the passed-in ones (or cause compilation errors).

Comment: there is a whole host of other problems with his code other that that

Comment: @sukhvir, I don't doubt that, those are just the ones that immediately popped out. However, they don't really have anything to do with the question asked, so I'll clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem comes from the fact that 1 is recognized as an int and not a float.

When you write `%.2f` scanf expects you to input a float. If it detects something else it fails and does not read any other scanf requests as specified in the man page.