# Declarations, Definitions and Calls

Tags: c++, c, declaration

i need to gain a better understanding of function definition, declarations and proper calls using this program. I really need the understanding of how to use them. Could you show me the proper way to write this program with all three correct and explained?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

quad_equation(float a, float b, float c);

int main()

{

    float a, b, c, determinant, r1,r2;

    printf("Enter coefficients a, b and c: ");

    scanf("%f%f%f",&a,&b,&c);

    determinant=b*b-4*a*c;

    if (determinant>0)

    {

        r1= (-b+sqrt(determinant))/(2*a);

        r2= (-b-sqrt(determinant))/(2*a);

        printf("Roots are: %.2f and %.2f",r1 , r2);

    }

    else if (determinant==0) { r1 = r2 = -b/(2*a);

    printf("Roots are: %.2f and %.2f", r1, r2);

    }


    else (determinant<0);

    {

    printf("Both roots are complex");

    }

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this exact question here : (I guess this is a part of an assignment )

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19826495/1253932

Also looking at your code .. you never use the function quad equation  .. also you haven't defined the type of the function ( int/void/float/char) etc.

**For ease:** ( here is the entire code ) -- ask me if you don't understand anything

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

// function declarations

void twoRoots (float a,float b,float delta);
void oneRoot (float a,float b,float delta);

 int main (void)                        
    {
    //Local Declarations
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float delta;

   // float solution;

    printf("Input coefficient a.\n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Input coefficient b.\n");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("Input coefficient c.\n");
    scanf("%f", &c);
    printf("%0.2fx^2 + %0.2fx + %0.2f\n", a, b, c);

    delta = (float)(b*b) - (float)(4.0 * a * c);

    printf("delta = %0.2f\n",delta);

    if (delta > 0){
         twoRoots(a,b,delta);
    }else if (delta == 0) {
         oneRoot(a,b,delta);
    }else if (delta < 0.0){
         printf("There are no real roots\n");
    }

    return 0;
} 

void twoRoots (float a,float b,float delta)
{

    float xOne;
    float xTwo;

    float deltaRoot;

    printf("There are two distinct roots.\n");
    deltaRoot = sqrt(delta);
    xOne = (-b + deltaRoot) / (2*a);
    xTwo = (-b - deltaRoot) / (2*a);
    printf("%.2f", xOne);
    printf("%.2f", xTwo);
} 



void oneRoot(float a,float b,float delta)
{

    float xOne;
  //  float xTwo;
   // float deltaRoot;

    printf("There is exactly one distinct root\n");
    xOne = -b / (2*a);
    printf("%.2f", xOne);

}
```

**EDIT:**

A slightly more optimized and better functioning code that I made from the above mentioned code:

http://pastebin.com/GS65PvH6

**Edit2:**

From your comments you try to do this:

```
printf("Enter coefficients a, b and c: ");
scanf("%f%f%f",&a,&b,&c);
```

This will fail if you input something like this: `121`

Beacuse scanf will read the whole `121` into `a` and it will have nothing for `b`,`c` ( rather it will put \n(enter) into b and undefined into c )

So use the scanf the way I have used it in my code

Comment: THe first float solution 'unused varible declaration, and same with the very bottom xtwo and deltaroot.

Comment: @user2879277 just remove them ..  ok hang on .. i will edit the code

Comment: Yeah that is what i did, im rearranging some things because this is much different then what i was initially doing. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: ask me if you don't understand anything  .. also if this helped you please accept the answer

Comment: yup no problem but for some reason i get No real roots for every thing i type in and cant figure it out

Comment: @user2879277 can you tell me the input you are giving?

Comment: 1,2,1 is what i keep putting in

Comment: @user2879277 .. it is working for me .. on the new code ( see the pastebin link )

Comment: yes it worked for me wierd. i changed the way it inputs and that must have messed it up i, changed it to: printf("Input coefficient a, b, c\n"); that is what must have messed it up, im not sure why?
  
    scanf("\n%f%f%f",&a,&b,&c);

Comment: yes that will fail because scanf won't work that way ... it will read 121 in a amd it will have nothing for b,c and will put \n in them

Comment: so there isn't a way to put them in on order like that? feel like i have done it before but had to be diffrent. Again thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: doesn't ring a bell. So i assume i haven't

Answer (score 0):

OK - this is full of problems! I attempt to point them out, and show what "better" looks like. I hope this helps.

```
quad_equation(float a, float b, float c);
```

This is probably intended to be a "function prototype". A prototype tells the compiler "I am going to use this function later, and this is how it needs to be called, and the type it returns". You did not specify a return type; probably you want to use `int` to say whether you found roots or not, and print out the result in the function. Better would be to pass space for two return values as a parameter:

```
int quad_equation(float a, float b, float c, float* x1, float* x2);
```

Now we can use the `main` program to get input/output, and let the function solve the problem:

```
int main(void) {
{
float a, b, c, r1, r2;
int n;

// here you get the inputs; that seems OK
printf("Enter coefficients a, b and c: ");
scanf("%f %f %f",&a,&b,&c);

// now you have to "call your function"
// note that I make sure to follow the prototype: I assign the return value to an int
// and I pass five parameters: the coefficients a, b, c and the address of two variables
// x1 and x2. These addresses will be where the function puts the roots
n = quad_equation(a, b, c, &r1, &r2);

// when the function returns, I can print the results:
printf("There are %d roots:\n", n);

// based on the value of n, I change what I want to print out:
if (n == 2) printf(" %f and ", r1);  // when there are two roots I print "root 1 and"
if (n > 0) printf("%f\n", r2);       // when there is at least one root, I print it
// note that if n == 0, I would skip both print statements
// and all you would have gotten was "There are 0 roots" in the output

}

int quad_equation(float a, float b, float c, float* x1, float* x2) {
// function that computes roots of quadratic equation
// and returns result in x1 and x2
// it returns the number of roots as the return value of the function

float determinant;

  determinant=b*b-4*a*c;

  if (determinant>0)
  {
    *x1 = (-b+sqrt(determinant))/(2*a);
    *x2= (-b-sqrt(determinant))/(2*a);
    return 2;
  }

if (determinant==0) { 
  *x1 = *x2 = -b/(2*a);
  return 1;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: ON the declaration i was wondering what the "*" next to the float is for? Also the R1 and R2  are they suppose to be X1 and X2 in the bottom?

Comment: The * means that this is not a `float`, but a _pointer_ to a float - i.e. This variable contains the _address of a location where a float is stored_. This allows the function to modify the contents of that location - and so it can pass more than one value back to the calling program. I deliberately gave them a different name in the function, because that is one of the things you can do: the name of the variable you use to define it does not need to be the name of the variable you call it with.